# getAttributeText in a safe way / test if attribute exist in product first

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, product, attributes, product-attribute

If I call getAttributeText on a non existing attribute, eg:

```
$product->getAttributeText('some-non-existing-field');
```

I get the fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object
```

Which I can't even try-catch because its fatal.

Different magento stores have different attributes (And also different products got different attributes), so how can I access attributes in a safe way that even if they are undefined I won't get fatal (for example get null or empty string if non-existence)?

or as an alternative, how can I test if attribute exists first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answering self:

https://tahiryasin.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/get-custom-attribute-value-in-magento/

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute_code');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Given that the product is already loaded (including this attribute), you can use `getData()` instead of the magic getter to be able to use a dynamic attribute code:

```
$attributeCode = 'custom_attribute_code');

if ($_product->getData($attributeCode) !== null){
    echo $_product->getAttributeText($attributeCode);
}
```

This way you have no unnecessary database queries.

Comment: "This way you have no unnecessary database queries." - what do you mean?  is my answer below causing extra db queries? thanks

Comment: I double checked, your solution is actually the same as `getAttributeText()` with an additional check, so it's fine. I thought it would load a single attribute from the database but apparently I was wrong. That makes our answers equally efficient.

Comment: but yours a little more elegant ;) thanks!

Comment: works on magento2.4 

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
if($product->getCustomAttributeCode()) {
    echo $product->getAttributeText('custom_attribute_code');   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using short-hand PHP:

```
echo $_product->getCustomAttributeCode()?$_product->getAttributeText('custom_attribute_code'):"";
```